# Unity AR project framerate issue Samsung Tablet, not on Samsung S8

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Running two AR scenes, both use Vuforia for image detection. One scene is a simple AR pop-up book type project, the other scene creates a portal over the detected image.

I developed both scenes on my S8 without any issue, but now I'm running the project on a Samsung Tab A (2016) and the portal scene runs incredibly slowly, its completely unusable. However, the popup scene runs great. I know the S8 has higher specs but it shouldn't make that much of a difference, right?

Anyway, I'm fairly new to Unity, App development and AR so I've struggled to debug the scene. These are my screens of the Profiler. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Profiler Screenshot 1]

[image: Profiler Screenshot 2]

[image: Profiler Screenshot 3]

Comment: How do you think anyone should figure this out?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot hoping the profiler will give someone with more experience an insight into what could be wrong, it might even just be an option in the Player Settings, just thought it would be worth asking whilst I tried to debug it myself

Comment: Opaque objects seems to be the issue according to the profiler. Disable the models run it and see if the performance increase. If it did, enable the models one by one and test with the profiler to see which one or how many appears before it starts to slow down.

Comment: I've worked with the s7 and the tab A2016 and with vuforia. The phone has a much higher resolution than the tab, which could be the source of your problems